# Cardinality of Lo Category

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to figure out the cardinality of Unicode categories like `Lo`. It seems I cannot find an authoritative information about that. E.g. [Fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/index.htm) maintains the view there are `11788` characters in this category, [Codepoints.net](http://codepoints.net/search?gc=Lo) is as low as `122`, and Python's `unicodedata`, even if restricted to the Basic Plane, gives as much as `45301`!:

```
In [219]: Lo=[unichr(c) for c in xrange(65536) 
              if unicodedata.category(unichr(c)) == 'Lo']

In [220]: len(Lo)
Out[220]: 45301
```

Can anybody point me to a reliable source to resolve this?!

EDIT:

The result for `len(Lo)` in the Python snippet depends on the version of [UCD](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/) used, and hence on the Python version. My result was with Python 2.6 which uses UCD version 5.1, Python 2.7 with UCD 5.2 yields `45877` for the same expression, and Python 3.2 with UCD 6.0 would probably yield yet another number.

Comment: I've got `45877` on narrow python build

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 45877 here also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive information would be the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/) itself.  In particular, information on the character database is available [here](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/) which provides information on the Unicode Character Database.  The current standard has 11788 Lo categorised code-points.

Comment: Excellent, although you have to dig as deep as to this file (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) to actually figure out the answer. Now the question remains why Python's `unicodedata` module is such a long way off ...

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the docs for Python `unicodedata`:

> This module provides access to the Unicode Character Database which
>   defines character properties for all Unicode characters. The data in
>   this database is based on the UnicodeData.txt file version 5.2.0 which
>   is publicly available from ftp://ftp.unicode.org/.
>
> The module uses the same names and symbols as defined by the
>   UnicodeData File Format 5.2.0 (see
>   http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-4.html). It defines the
>   following functions:

And the Unicode Consortium in their "about us":

> The Unicode Consortium is a non-profit organization devoted to
>   developing, maintaining, and promoting software internationalization
>   standards and data, particularly the Unicode Standard, which specifies
>   the representation of text in all modern software products and
>   standards. The Unicode Consortium actively develops standards in the
>   area of internationalization including defining the behavior and
>   relationships between Unicode characters. The Consortium works closely
>   with W3C and ISO—in particular with ISO/IEC/JTC 1/SC2/WG2, which is
>   responsible for maintaining ISO/IEC 10646, the International Standard
>   synchronized with the Unicode Standard.

Looking at the main page, it would appear that the current standard is 6.1 (May 2012) so it's possible that since version 5.2 (Oct 2009), some "Lo" characters have been reclassified.

Check: http://www.unicode.org

Comment: thanks, good point, but even looking at the 5.2.0 data, grepping for 'Lo' yields `10584`. It appears strange that `unicodedata` module is off roughly by a factor of 4...

Comment: @ThomasH: grepping for `'Lo'` yuilds wrong result for the current standard 11790. `';Lo;'` produces 11788.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian To be precise, I was using `egrep -c -e '\bLo\b'` in both cases, which also yields 11788 for the current data.

Comment: @ThomasH Based on 5.2 - there's `21829` lines.. Of which, `7189` are classified as "Lo" - however, taking all codepoints in `range(65536)` **not in** UnicodeData.txt - and applying `unicodedata.category(unichr(i))` yields the following: `{'Cs': 2042, 'Lo': 38688, 'Co': 6398, 'Cn': 2724}` - so the `45877` is the ` `7189 + 38688` - s'pose the question is - what logic is `unicodedata.category` using to categorise this outside of `UnicodeData.txt`?

Comment: @JonClements You've got it. Looking at UnicodeData.txt, and only up to code point FFFF (65535), there are three *ranges* given where *First*, *Last* have category 'Lo'. I guess if you flat out those ranges and count the code points you'll end up with your `38688`. - I'm still not getting the `45877` (using Python 2.6), though...

Comment: @JonClements Ah, you are probably using Python 3 (.2?), which uses UCD 6.0.0 internally. That might account for the difference between 45301 and 45877.

Comment: @ThomasH Nope, `Python 2.7.3` with UCD 5.1

Comment: @ThomasH Sorry, I typoed - UCD 5.2

Comment: @JonClements Ah yes, on another machine with Python 2.7.3, it says using UCD 5.2, and I'm actually getting the 45877!

Comment: @ThomasH and the docs at http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/library/unicodedata.html state 2.6.8 uses UCD 5.1 - but still doesn't explain the logic behind `unicodedata.category` and I don't have the time to look at the src

Comment: @JonClements No worries. I looked at the source, and it has a non-trivial representation for the data. But I'm confident the logic is straight-forward when you count in all the ranges from UnicodeData.txt that have category 'Lo'.